# Why doesn't a variable increment in my React component as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm a React learner and I want to understand something. The code below doesn't work, it's just a component with two buttons that add or substract a number and display it. Here's the whole code :

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Compteur = () => {
  let i = 0;
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    i++;
    setNumber(i);
  };

  const decrement = () => {
    i--;
    setNumber(i);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={increment}>
        +
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={decrement}>
        -
      </button>
      <p>Number : {number}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Compteur;
```

But if I replace setNumber(i) by setNumber(number + 1), it works well. What's the problem with this i variable ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: The scope of `i` and the functions that capture it are remade every render. It needs to also use `useState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to React!

The problem in your example is that each time the component rerenders (in your case due to a state change), `i` is reinitialized and assigned a value of `0`. I think you're thinking of the component more as a loop, versus a javascript file.  React does a great job as maintaining state, and that state will stay the same though rerenders of the component, which is why it's working as expected when you use `number` (a piece of React state) instead of `i`

Comment: also, side note, instead of `setNumber(number +1)`, you'll want to do `setNumber((prevState) => prevState + 1)` since updates to state are asynchronous and the first way can lead to some unexpected behavior.

Comment: @DaveVanFleet In this case I think you're actually going to be fine, because you're not relying on it to update another piece of state. You're right that you can't rely on these to be synchronous, but because of how it's written it doesn't need to be, `setNumber(number + 1)` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem here is setting `let i = 0;` as react code is rerun on every rerender, which is caused by state change (among other ways).

So when you call `setNumber` react then says "okay, rerender the page" and it makes its way down your code, and sees "set i to be 0" and then when you increment the code is saying "i++" or in this case "0 + 1" (because i is set to 0 again).

Essentially, every time react rerenders the component, it's going to reset the value in the variable. That's why we have to use `useState` because react is then able to keep track of those values.

Your example `setNumber(number + 1)` is how you should be writing this.

Comment: Thank you ! I better understand how it works !

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable `i` which is getting reinitalized every render, your code should be something like this

```js
const increment = () => {
    setNumber(number + 1);
}

const decrement = () => {
    setNumber(number - 1);
}
```

Comment: This is not quite right, as `number++` will attempt to change the value of `number` which is not valid for react state updates. You instead would have to write `setNumber(number + 1)`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Forgot that ++ and -- are also assignment operators